# apache rewritten URL contains full Linux path

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I'm attempting to use the following Apache rewrite rule in a .htaccess file to strip trailing slashes from URLs.  I've seen this solution in a number of threads in various forums:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

This is causing the URL

```
http://www.domain.com/widgets/
```

to be rewritten as

```
http://www.domain.com/usr/local/www/apache22/data/domain/widgets
```

The RewriteRule is preceded by a number of explicit 301 redirects, and it's followed by other rewrite conditions and rules, but the same thing happens even if it's the only statement in the .htaccess file.

This problem is happening on both my linux server and my XAMPP server.  In windows, the URL gets rewritten as

```
http://www.domain.com/C:/xampp/htdocs/domain/widgets
```

If I remove the "L" from the rule, a 301 gets logged in the apache log, but no rewrite occurs.

Here's the vhost entry for this domain:

```
<VirtualHost X.X.X.X:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
    DocumentRoot "/usr/local/www/apache22/data/domain"
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ErrorLog "/var/log/apache22/domain-error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/apache22/domain-access.log" combined
    <Directory /usr/local/www/apache22/data/domain>
        AllowOverride FileInfo
    </Directory>
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 week"
        ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 week"
        ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 week"
        ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 week"
        ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 week"
        ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
        ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 week"
        ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 week"
        ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 1 week"
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any suggestions about what might be happening?

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like mod_rewrite is mistaking a file-path with a URI-path. Try adding a leading slash to your rule's target:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

However, keep in mind that mod_dir and the `DirectorySlash` directive (which is turned on by default) will redirect all requests to directories/folders that are missing the trailing slash to the same URL with a trailing slash, and this rule will create a redirect loop. You could circumvent that by including a condition before the rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Placing a slash before $1 didn't fix it. The URI string still got converted to a filesystem path.

Comment: @dcorsello make sure you've cleared your cache, since it's a 301, your browser will cache it.

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I use a macro so it's impossible to hardcode domain. I use `RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1` and that redirects to `https://example.com/var/www/full/path/`